# Java Nested Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I came across a code base that read a text file and analyzes it. I am bit confused with the way the exceptions are used. A separate class `AppFileReaderException` that `extends` exceptions has been defined where the extended class only returns the error message for the exception. Besides, the function `getSymbol()` uses both `throws` and `try and catch block`. The `error()` function has an exception handler too which could result in nested exceptions ! Is there any advantage of doing such exception handling where the basic try and catch should be sufficient? Is there any reason to extend the exception class, combine both `throws` and `try-catch` block? Are these over kill or there is a good reason to have such constructs?

```
package AppName;    
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;

public class AppFileReader {


    // 
    public char getSymbol() throws AppFileReaderException {
        try {

        //do something

       } catch (Exception e) {
            error("IO Error: " + fileName + "@" + currentLineNumber);
        }
        return somechar;
    }


    public void error(String errorMsg) throws AppFileReaderException {
        throw new AppFileReaderException(errorMsg);
    }

    public AppFileReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

}
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------

The extended class for the `AppFileReaderException` is as follows:

```
package AppName;
public class AppFileReaderException extends Exception {


    public AppFileReaderException(String msg) 
    {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the `error()` method (not function!) does not have any handling. It just throws an exception with the given message.

Creating your own exception classes may be useful when calling the methods; so you can do something like

```
public void methodThatCallsLibrary() {
   try {
      doSomething();
      new AppFileReader().getSymbol();
      doOtherSomething();
   } catch (AppFileReaderException afre) {
     // handling specific to appFileReader
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // handling related to the rest of the code.
   }
}
```

That said, the system here is a Little odd. By creating the exception in the `error()` method, the stacktrace of the exception is the same for all the possible places where an exception is raised. Also, it looks like that it just masks IOException, so I would probably go for forwarding the IOException itself (and, if not, include the nested exception in the exception that is finally thrown, to give a better debugging information).

Answer (score 2):

Deriving your own exceptions from the base exception class is a very good idea since

1) you can deal with different exception objects separately.

2) functions often have "throws ..." suffixed to them which tells the caller what exceptions to expect. This helps program stability.

Remember that java has a multicatch exception syntax:

Catch (exception1 | exception2 | ... e) where e is the caught object. Use this if you want to deal with such exception types equivalently.

Answer (score 0):

The system of checked and unchecked exceptions in Java was experimental, but the most programmers believe this was not a good concept. Additionally, the checked exception hierarchy is bad designed, for example, if you do something with reflection, you have to catch 4 or 5 separate exceptions.

In practice, almost every bean code in modern web application invokes some functions that do something with IO, SQL (and probably reflection) so with checked exception system, you'd have a lot of exceptions to handle or to add to function signature.

A programming model for Java, proposed for example in Spring, is to handle exceptions transparently. You have an interface for service, the implementation can use WebService, SQL database or anything else. How can you know what exceptions to handle and how? Therefore, you provide your own exception hierarchy that you can handle in single place.

Spring also wraps all exceptions in `NestedRuntimeException`.

You can also handle exceptions in **aspects** or **filters**. In that case the exceptions should be fully transparent for your business code. You separate fully exception handling from normal processing.